# Nikon D5300: How to switch default dial behavior (aperture vs shutter)

Tags: camera-settings

In manual mode, the dial on the Nikon D5300 controls shutter speed. To adjust aperture, you must hold down the exposure button while turning the dial. Is it possible to switch this so the default is aperture and the shutter is adjusted by holding down the exposure button? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the *User Manual* for the D5300?

Comment: To clarify: I want to stay in full manual, not go to aperture priority. The settings menu does not contain an obvious option for this, and I couldn't find an option in the manual, hence the question. Would be great if there's an easy way to do this! Thanks

Comment: To clarify: There's not an easy way to to do this with the D5300. Short of writing a new firmware version that includes the option there's not any way at all to do this with the D5300.

Comment: The higher end Nikon DSLRs have this feature, even the "prosumer" ones, I cannot imagine why they wouldn't offer it on the D5300. Seems like the kind of thing that would be more trouble than it's worth to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the lack of such an option in the *Controls* section of the camera's *Custom Menu*, I would say not. See page 183 in the [*Nikon D5300 Reference Manual*](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive1/nDjd000XOIQF00mktpj7624w9V96/D5300RM_(En)01.pdf) for details.

One possible workaround would be to shoot in *Aperture-priority* or **A** exposure mode. In **A** mode turning the command dial would control the aperture. Pressing the exposure compensation button and turning the command dial would change the exposure compensation setting which would directly alter the shutter speed. In certain specific situations you might need to turn *Auto ISO Sensitivity* off for *exposure compensation* to directly affect shutter speed. Of course the beginning point would be dependent upon the meter reading each time you pressed the shutter button halfway.